# Polynomial Long Division

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck on a problem and working though it I can't find how the comparison is going wrong. I am trying to do polynomial long division modulo 2.

```
while len(binCrcGen) <= len(binPayload) and binPayload:
        if binPayload[0] == binCrcGen[0]:
                del binPayload[0]
                for j in range(len(binCrcGen)-1):
                        if binPayload[j] == binCrcGen[j+1]:
                                binPayload.insert(binPayload[j],0)
                                del binPayload[j+1]
                                print(binPayload, "binPayload")
                        else:
                                binPayload.insert(binPayload[j],1)
                                del binPayload[j+1]
                                print(binPayload, "binPayload")
```

However my output gives me:

```
Input the binary data payload: 10010
Input the binary representation of the CRC generator: 11
[1, 0, 1, 0] binPayload
[1, 1, 0] binPayload
[1, 0] binPayload
[1] binPayload -- wrong here 1 xor 1 should bring 0 to list.
[1] Remainder
[1, 1] binCrCGen
The data transmitted with the payload 1001 is protected by the CRC 11 is 10011
```

And when calculating it by hand I get a remainder of 00 which turns to a blank list as blank lists are deleted out.

Comment: Your function goes into an infinite loop in the `binPayload[0] != binCrcGen[0]` case.

Comment: Why are you doing that weird insert/del thing instead of `binPayload[j] = whatever`?

Comment: `for j in range(len(binCrcGen)-1)` are you sure it is not `for j in range(len(binCrcGen))`?

Comment: `binPayload.insert(binPayload[j], 1)` doesn't insert into `binPayload` at location `j`. If `binPayload[j]` is 0, this will insert at location 0. You could fix this with `binPayload.insert(j, 1)`, but it'd be better to ditch the insert/del thing and just use `binPayload[j] = 1`.

Comment: @user2357112 there is no infinite loop.

Comment: @BobDunakey: You *know* your code doesn't work. Why would you respond to people pointing out the problems with a flat assertion that there is no such problem?

Comment: @user2357112 Wasn't anything personal I just tested for infinite loops and didn't see any.

Comment: Try it with `binPayload = [0, 1, 0, 1]` and `binCrcGen = [1, 1]`.

Comment: @user2357112 remainder 1 which is wrong it should be remainder 0.

Comment: @RafiKamal I get out of index errors if I don't. But yes I am certain as it relates to the algorithm.

Comment: @BobDunakey: Then your actual code's logic is something entirely different from what you've posted. When I copy/paste your code into an interpreter with `binPayload` changed to `[0, 1, 0, 1]`, I get an infinite loop.

Comment: @user2357112 didn't add the entire code  I just noticed. look at bottom should updated with  removed 0's out front to stop that from happening as leading 0's don't do anything in polynomial modulo  2.

Comment: @user2357112 your my hero your comment on binPayload.insert(j, 1)  fixed it. just noticed I changed something after posting this and I changed it back and this worked.

Comment: It's good that you're acknowledging the error, but don't remove the question and replace it all with the fix... that's what the answers are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is on these lines:

```
                                binPayload.insert(binPayload[j],0)
                                binPayload.insert(binPayload[j],1)
```

You're not inserting at index `j`. You're inserting at index 0 or 1, depending on what `binPayload[j]` is. To fix it, change the index to `j` instead of `binPayload[j]`. While you're at it, you can remove the weird insert/del thing you're using and just use `binPayload[j] = whatever`. Also, you can use the exclusive-or operator `^` to remove the if/else, and you can use the in-place version `^=` to save some repetition:

```
binCrcGen  = [1,1]
binPayload = [1,0,0,1,0]

while len(binCrcGen) <= len(binPayload) and binPayload:
    if binPayload[0] == binCrcGen[0]:
        del binPayload[0]
        for j in range(len(binCrcGen)-1):
            binPayload[j] ^= binCrcGen[j+1]
        print(binPayload, "binPayload")
    while binPayload and binPayload[0] == 0:
        del binPayload[0]
        print(binPayload, "binPayload")
```

Comment: Yup you got it your the best. Thanks. I however have to  edit my original post as I don't want class mates possibly trying to use my code and causing that kind of mess.

Comment: @BobDunakey: Don't remove your original code; it'll make it harder for people to understand what's going on in the question. If you want to post a revised version, you can edit it in above your original code with a clear label showing that it's the fixed version.